# need of Static variables and their overhead on jvm

Tags: java, interface, jvm, static-members

As per the concept about static members, they are created/loaded into the memory when there is first call made to its class. And they are common among all instances of that class. Means they are not re-created or re-itialized etc. In addition, They can be accessed by the class name only. There is no need to create object for that class just to access them.

Now my questions are;

1. Whether static members ever be in
   memory till the application is
   running? even if all the instances
   of that class had been collected by
   GC(garbage collector).
2. For a big project, where 8-10 teams
   are working together, they dont care
   about the coding of other's team.
   They may create static members as
   per their need. If all the members
   are cached in memory, would it not
   create overhead over JVM?
3. By default, all the members of interfaces are STATIC and the use of interfaces are good in many cases. But if i keep my above questions in mind, should i still use interfaces?

Comment: `Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.` -- Donald Knuth

Comment: This is a case of missing the forest for the trees. In my entire professional career, I have always encountered memory leaks arising out of non-static members being leaked. While those concerns quoted in the question may be valid, they are hardly the cause of load on a JVM.

Comment: To continue, my guess is that when all is said and done, you will be wishing you put more time and effort into code readability, re-usability, high cohesion and low coupling than in worrying about the minutia of variable footprint.

Comment: If you are concerned that your big project will run into trouble because of too many static variables turning up in the code, try to encourage unit-testing. Static variables makes unit-testing difficult so developers will hopefully turn to designing code without them unless really needed.

Comment: +1 for this vry good suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Static members are garbage collected only when the class that defines them is itself collected; this in turn can only happen if the defining ClassLoader is collected. This is common in web application containers and plugin architectures.

2) Yes, defining a large amount of static data can be a bad idea. But it's like a lot of other things: it's good if you need it, and bad if you abuse it. Just use common sense.

3) Again, an interface that defined an array of a thousand Strings would be a bad idea, but of course that's not normally what people do. Just use common sense. There's no (memory-related) reason to avoid static variables in general.

Comment: Hey, Ernest are you a rancher? Just curious if you are the one.... I loved your posts there and you helped me many times.

Comment: Important to say: 1) will not happen during the lifetime of the application, but only when an enterprise application is stopped and in turn re-deployed on an application server.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari: yep, that's me. I recognized your name, too. Nice to see you here!

Comment: @Ernest: Good to hear that you recognised my name too. BTW, 10k in 2 months, WOW! Keep it going...

Comment: @Ernest, please compare your first point with @BertNase answer

Comment: @articlestack: don't know how to say this gently, so: I'm right and he's wrong :) A unique class in Java is actually defined not just by a class name but by a [class, classloader] pair. The same class file can be loaded in more than one classloader. A "singleton" can therefore actually exist multiple times. One of those copies can be garbage-collected if no code can ever access it: i.e., if no thread's stack contains a reference to any objects created from classes loaded by that classloader. In that case, since that singleton instance can never be accessed by running code, it can be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes. No GC will ever clean up static variables. This is important because otherwise one could not rely on values stored in static variables. Design patterns like "Singleton" rely on static variables.
2. The static variables take as much mem as the same value stored in instance variable, so as long as the value stored in the variable is really necessary for the abblication, there is no particular storage overhead in static variables. But the side-effects iposed by the use of  static variables when it comes to thread-safety etc. need to be considered more thatn the memory issues.
3. yes. But Interfaces are there for describing the contract between provider and user of functionality, not for storing any data.

Comment: 1) Interfaces also stores data "final static public" variaable, 2) Please compare your point(1) with @Ernest point(1)

Answer (score 0):

1. No, they are collected with the class.
2. Overhead compared to what? What's the alternative?
3. Yes, but nobody said you have to fill them up with static members.

Comment: Overhead compared to nothing. If something is not giving good results, people invent new things. they don't stop since there is no existing alternative

Comment: @articlestack: 'overhead compared to nothing' is meaningless. Either the variables are required or they aren't. If they're not needed, don't create them. I don't know what your 2nd and 3rd sentences mean re this question.

Comment: I think pure abstract class could be an alternate of interface. (I know its disadvantage like a class can inherit only one class but implement many interfaces.)

Comment: @articlestack of course it's an alternative, but the overhead is identical.