# Handling static variables in Application class in android

Tags: java, android

I have an application with 100+ static variables and methods in its Application class will it affect the performance of the app? if so how to handle it?

Comment: maybe your design is a bit wrong though

Comment: any alternate way to handle it?

Comment: use preferences keeping static variable consumes memory as those are alive untill you class or in this case application is active.

Comment: Create a helper class and put them in it!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196027/need-of-static-variables-and-their-overhead-on-jvm

Comment: @shadoWalker that would not be any better. The main problem with static variables in Android is that the OS can throw the app out of memory when it is in background and the memory is otherwise needed. When the app is then restarted all the values are lost.

Comment: @Henry, I don't think that he is trying to save his data in static variables. I think his wants to access them everywhere in his app.

Comment: what if i move all the variables and methods to a normal class and access it with singleton objects. it makes any difference by using application class and normal class.

Comment: @shadoWalker The problem still remains, see the activity life cycle: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and in particular the method `onSaveInstanceState` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: i will remove the static access to all and access it with objects.is that works?

Comment: Creating instances and make an object singleton, has their own definition and are used in right places. And from where I see, you don't need them.

Comment: Too much static variables? Then that is bad implementation. Reduce the use of static, and when it is absolutely necessary use static

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your only question is if using `static` methods and variables inside your application class is wrong or not. As far as I know, it will not affect your application performance or anything else, but putting them inside application class is a wrong design. It's like you put all your code inside one single method and it will not be good.

So, I suggest you to put your `static` methods inside a `Helper` class and since they don't need to be instantiated, they need to be `static`, not a `singleton`. Also for your variables, for example for your `String`s, I suggest to create another class and put them into it so your application maintenance be possible.

Comment: If the number of static variables increases, more memory is consumed.

Comment: See for example this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797187/android-static-variable-null-on-low-memory why this is not a good idea.

Comment: Guys his question is not what you are answering. I agree with both of you, but his question is another thing.